# How can I create a response with rich messages in Dialogflow to Twilio?

Tags: image, twilio, dialogflow-es

I am using Dialogflow integrated into Twilio to send SMS messages back and forth via text.  I am wondering if/how I can send a response that is an image.  I have the image loaded as a url on the web that I am trying to include as an image in the response but I cannot get it to work.

Thanks so much for any help

Mike

Comment: please show us what you tried, code?

Comment: I have tried a bunch

{"mediaURL": "https://www.elevatebankers.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/Banker-Ed.png"}

I also gave up on DialogFLow and tried on Amazon Lex with similar results
On Lex I tried doing a ResponseCard after doing some research but that produced no results either
Thanks for any help

Comment: Hi Mike, I can help more on the Twilio side, If you look at Twilio Autopilot, you can use the show action, as defined here, https://www.twilio.com/docs/autopilot/actions/show. Autopilot is Twilio Natural Language Understanding (NLU) Platform. https://www.twilio.com/autopilot.

Answer (score -1):

I worked with Twilio a lot for sms and I tried myself Autopilot but the issue with Twilio is not a rich content kind of engine. Twilio will only post images to it, so you can "mimic" a rich response with an image but if you click that image nothing happens. I gave up on Twilio and change to Dialogflow in which I can create rich context out of the box for facebook, skype, etc but also I can integrate it with Kommunicate and have a hybrid bot human engine with web integration for chat that also support rich content.

Comment: Thanks Ray & Alan.  Ray, I like the idea of just Dialogbox but I want my chatbot to be interactive via text messaging - I don't see if Kommunicate can do that - seems like just online and in app - am I correct?

Comment: Hi Mike! Yes but I have almost the same setup so my decision was to connect Twilio for sms but remember that sms does not support rich messages, is all text and images. Your only option is to create an image simulating your rich response but is not like a suggestion chip that you can click and it will write back your selection to the bot. If you want to be more user friendly you need to use rich channels such a as web, messenger, etc.  All of them are supported by DialogFlow but Kommunicate enhanced a lot the web channel and chat solution by giving you additional flexibility, if needed.